# PHP Insert / Update a mysql table from HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my first mysql table.

I use HTML form in order to insert datas into a mysql table.

When submited, the form calls a php script in order to add datas into the form.

Then, mySQL table could look as follow :

[image]

From this mySQL table how could i generate and display a HTML table sorted by "NEXT_EVENT" column ?

If i want go on step ahead, is there a way a let user click on an upward / downward arrow placed next to each column header (links) in order to get the HTML table sorted as the desired column ?

--

Once the table sorted, i need to generate a raw simple TXT file where the ID on very FIRST row and NEXT_EVENT values will be copied to.

ie, sort.txt : 
the 2 fields are comma separed.

2,    1499005140

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY NEXT_EVENT;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have such a link next to the heading you can use jQuery plugin tablesorter. You can refer at

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

And for just executing a query for one column, you can use ORDER BY clause

Hope it helps